# Salesforce Custom metadata edit access

Tags: custom-metadata

Is there any way to provide **edit** access to records of custom metadata, but without ***Customize Application*** permission. Customize application gives really wide access and we want to avoid it, but till now couldn't find any related topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for this you have to build custom solutions and you can use metadata API to insert/update records of Custom Metadata.

You can refer to this link - https://www.pantherschools.com/create-update-custom-metadata-using-apex/

Comment: is there any way using just standard permissions?

Comment: No, I don't think so.